# Bluetooth Hands Free Profile (HFP) just call notification, no audio?

Tags: qt, bluetooth, notifications, phone-call

I write an QT application on my laptop (Debian 8). I want to be notified if there is a new call on my phone available (Android).

Is it possible to just notify the laptop without being the laptop a headset?

I already managed to get a connection to the HFP, and my laptop gets a 'RING' signal, but when i want to answer the call, my mobile phone shows a bluetooth speaker /headset connected (in call display) and everything what is spoken is lost on both mobile phones.

So it would be great to just notify about a new call.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to keep the audio stay at mobile phone side; is there SCO/eSCO connect/disconnect API's on your laptop? if yes, just reject the audio connect request, or disconnect/switch the audio if it connected.

There are may no audio handler on your PC yet so you could not found the audio.

Comment: Hey, i am not sure if there is an API or drivers for it. I found just a bt-sco package, but it is just for ubuntu. So i always have to "accept" the whole call? There is no way for just a notification?

Comment: sorry i was not check the API either but did you have any chance to find out the API/config files something like switchAudio or other kind of audio operations?

Comment: The development of the application on the laptop is just the first step. The final application should run on an embedded device with just a speaker, no microphone. So a 'normal' headset functionality is pointless there. Just a notification about a new call is neccessary / important. At the moment i disconnect the laptop from the HFP service and a dialog appears. When the call is over (on the smartphone) the user had to check the dialog an the HFP service will reconnects to laptop.

Comment: In this case you may not need to develop the program on laptop but directly on your embedded device. or, does your device using the same stack i.e. bluez with laptop? basically you do not need disconnect the hfp but just switch audio can resolve your problem.

Comment: The embedded device will run bluez too. Switch audio: Is this part of the bluetooth profile or part of the device?

Comment: It's an HF profile command but on low level, it was part of device, can you found the interface named "sco_connect".